# how to loop through sessionScope in SSJS / XPages?

Tags: collections, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a function to go through all sessionScopes:

```
function clearMap( map:Map ){ // Get iterator for the keys
    var iterator = map.keySet().iterator();  // Remove all items 
    while( iterator.hasNext() ){  
        //would like to read here the keyValue
    }
}

clearMap(sessionScope);
```

I would like to read the key value for each item in the map. (keys ending with _languagecode I would like to remove) but how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `iterator.next()`you have access to the key itself so you should be able to do something like this in SSJS:

```
function clearMap( map:Map ){ // Get iterator for the keys
    var iterator = map.keySet().iterator();  // Remove all items 
    while( iterator.hasNext() ){  
        var key = iterator.next();
        if (key == 'something you want to test for') {
            map.remove(key);
        }
    }
}
```